# Use a for loop variable to call a predefined variable

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, variables

I'm looking to use a variable which gets defined inside a for loop and use it to call a predefined variable.

For example: To start the program `"Slack"` I need to call the variable `%Slack%`.
The batch file will take your input, so If I input `"Slack"`, the variable `!filename[%%i]!` will be assigned `"Slack"`. Once that is done, I wish to call `%Slack%` using `!filename[%%i]!`. As per logic: `%!filename[%%i]!%`

Using `%!filename[%%i]!%` will make the batch file crash and close.

Setting `set file=!filename[%%i]!` and running it with `%file%` will return nothing.

Any smart trick?

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Predefined variables
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (D:\programs.txt) do set %%G=%%H

set /P "filenames=Enter programs to install: "

:: Puts input into array
set n=0
for %%a in (%filenames%) do (
    set /A n+=1
    set "filename[!n!]=%%~a"
)

:: Run variables imported from programs.txt
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (

    :: This is where I want !filename[%%i]! to be called as %!filename[%%i]!%

)

pause
endlocal
```

program.txt example

```
Slack=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\slack\slack.exe
Text=C:\textfile.txt
Program=C:\program.bat & C:\program_license.txt
```

Comment: It would be helpful if, in your question body, you also included, _(formatted as code)_, an example of the content of `D:\programs.txt`.

Comment: Nothing "crashes"; open a command prompt window and run the batch file from there by typing its path/name; then you can see any error messages; also temporarily remove `@echo off` and check all the command echoes. Anyway, `%!variable!%` makes no sense unless you have got a variable that is called `!variable!` (including the `!`, which is not the case here); why is `!variable!` not good enough for you?

Comment: @aschipfl because `!variable!` only returns `Slack`. With this string return I want to somehow use it to call a `%Slack%` variable (Defined from programs.txt at line 6).

Comment: `CALL echo %%!filename[%%i]!%%` or `CALL START "" %%!filename[%%i]!%%`

Comment: @Squashman Worked! Thank you.

Comment: Based upon your provided example, your initial `For` loop could look like this: `For /F "UseBackDelims=" %%A In ("D:\programs.txt")Do Set "%%A"`

Comment: @Compo Thank you. Always up for improvement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like to use the CALL hack described in the comments because 1), it is relatively slow, and 2) it causes an extra round of parsing that can require additional escaping (not an issue here). Even worse, it will corrupt quoted `^` - `"^"` becomes `"^^"`, and there is no escape sequence that can prevent that.

My solution is to add an additional FOR loop so that the expansion can be staged.

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do for %%A in ("!filename[%%i]!") do echo !%%~A!
```

This is certainly more verbose than the CALL hack, but it is a good code pattern to learn because it is more universally applicable.

Comment: Works fine as well. Replaced it with this. Thank you